# Higher Order Functions - Eloquent Javascript

Tags: javascript

Can someone please help me understand the below example. I think I am really close to getting it but something isn't clicking. I am confused about the relationship between the functions, specifically how the greaterThan10(11) exists without defining it earlier.

```
function greaterThan(n) {
  return function(m) { return m > n; };
}
var greaterThan10 = greaterThan(10);
console.log(greaterThan10(11));
```

Any nudge in the right direction would be appreciated!
JH

Comment: `how greaterThan10(11) exists without defining it earlier.` - you define it in the line above where you use it?

Comment: `greaterThan10` is the function returned by `greaterThan` with `n = 10`.

Answer (score 0):

`greaterThan` returns a function, with `n` specified when you call it.  The function it returns takes an argument and returns true if that argument is greater than `n`.

Calling `greaterThan(10)` returns a function like this:

```
  function greaterThan10(m) {
    var n = 10;
    return m > n;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

A functional language treats functions as first class citizens, they do not only exist in source code and compiled away, they are a real primitive that can be instantiated, stored, and passed around, just like a string or boolean etc, with the added ability to call them to run a routine.

A higher order function is typically named such because it either accepts functions as parameters, or returns a new function itself, and is normally used as a way to abstract, compose, decorate, or bind/partially apply functions.

In this case it returns a decorated function. In essence it is a factory, that creates a brand new function instance with the provided number baked in at runtime, rather than by you manually assigning `n` at the time of writing, it is provided when the HOC is called.

To explain how this works better, lets go back to what actually happens when you write a named function...

```
function foo(buzz) { 
  console.log(buzz) 
}
```

it creates a reference to a Function instance and assigns it to a variable named `foo`

This is better illustrated by constructor (the scope is different but that's for another time)...

```
const foo = new Function('buzz', 'console.log(buzz)')
foo('boom!') // logs 'boom!'
```

Or by assigning an anonymous function a variable (again scope differs but doesn't matter here)...

```
const foo = function(buzz) {
  console.log(buzz) 
}
foo('shackalacka') // logs 'shackalacka'
```

This Function instance has the routine you assigned, and is callable by the reference name, ie the variable name is `foo` so you can call it to execute it's routine via `foo('Nic Cage')`. However its just a reference so you can reassign it to any other name `const bar = foo` and calling it via that calls exactly the same Function instance...

```
foo('boom!') // logs 'boom!'
const bar = foo
bar('boom!') // logs 'boom!'
```

And because they are the same instance, they are equal by reference...

```
bar === foo // => true
```

**TLDR** A function is a real object instance, that can be dynamically created, and passed around by reference

The HOC takes that concept a step further by returning a brand new Function instance that is not completely defined directly by you in code, and is not already bound to a variable, so it can be assigned instead at runtime. This also enables it to use anything variable passed into it unknown to you when writing it (in this case `n`), at which point it will be locked to the value supplied. If supplied `n = 10` then beneath the surface your program just doing the following for you at runtime...

```
cont greaterThan10 = new Function('m', 'return m > 10')
```

In real world terms, an HOC is like writing recipe for generating further pie recipes. Once you've worked out pastry recipes and how to make a pie shape, the outer pie recipe is always the same but could have a few different pastry types, and whatever filling you feel like at the time. As chef of 'Pie Another Day' restaurant, sure you could go find your pie recipe and pastry recipe every time a new pie is on the menu, photocopy them, give them to your sous chefs and tell them to just combine them and add the filling in between, but they are inexperienced and all need an exact same copy of the full beef puff pastry pie recipe or it will be a disaster! An HOC for a generic pie allows you to generate a recipe for a pie of a particular pastry recipe (but without filling), and when you pass a filling it will generate a new recipe for that particular filling too, which you can save for later use, write down once and give to your sous chefs!

```
// I'm an exec chef and cleverly worked out a recipe that can make ANY pie with any pastry I want later without lifting a finger! 
function pieRecipe(pastryRecipe) {
  return function(filling) {
    pastryRecipe() + mashedUp(filling) + pastryRecipe() // this returns a further recipe for any pie with this pstry type
  }
}
const chouPieRecipe = pieRecipe(chouPastryRecipe) // any pie can now be made with chou pastry
const beefPieRecipe = chouPieRecipe('beef') // yay saved recipe for beef chou pie, now the exec chef can go do some daytime TV show
const beefPieLunch = beefPieRecipe() // yum customer loves it
const anotherBeefPieLunch = beefPieRecipe() // blurgh too much beef pie
// "err waiter, excuse me I need something for my indigestion!" 
// sous chef: "oh look Chef left his generic pie recipe lying around, but we have no chou left, hang on heres a recipe for shortcrust pastry, I can make you...."
const medicinePieLunch = pieRecipe(shortCrustRecipe)('indigestion tablets')() // just make me the actual pie right now, but lets not save the recipe, its gross!!
```